# homology groups of the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^2$ obtained by identifying north and south poles to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

**Compute the homology groups of the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^2$
obtained by identifying north and south poles to a point.**

I have already calculated the homology groups in one way, but I would like to calculate the homology groups also using the mayer vietoris sequence, so I am trying to find two open $U\subset X=\mathbb{S}^2/{\sim}$ and $V\subset X$ such that $X=U\cup V$, I have initially taken $U=X-\{(0,0,1)\}$ and $V=X-\{(1,0,0)\}$, but I do not know how these spaces look, could someone tell me which spaces are homotopic $U$ and $V$? Thank you.

Comment: Surely you can figure out what $U$ is, at least.

Comment: @EricWofsey 
I find it more difficult to figure $U$ than $V$. It will not be that $V\simeq\mathbb{S}^1$?

Answer (score 3):

You can draw your space in the following way:

[image]

It looks a bit like a nice croissant. The $U$ and $V$ you have given are (as Eric Wofsey points out in the comments) your space $X$ without the identification point and $X$ with any other point removed, respectively. While $U$ is an open annulus, I don’t see a space that $V$ is homotopic to that has homology groups I know immediately. Thus, I would suggest a different choice.

Here, the blue portion in the picture above should be your $U$ and the red portion should be your $V$. Thus $U$ is an open annulus which is homotopic to a circle, and $V$ is the wedge sum of two disks which is homotopic to a point.

---

This will help you formally compute the homology groups. That said, I think it can often be helpful to “find” the answer before you “know” the answer. We can do this by drawing your space is as the following quotient of a torus:

[image]

where we identify all points on the pink circle. Since the pink circle is a generator of one $\mathbb{Z}$ in the first homology of the torus, this is squashed to $0$ in the first homology of our space — and nothing else has changed. Thus, we should expect that since

$$H_n(T^2) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & n=0,2 \\ \mathbb{Z}^2 & n=1 \\ 0 & n\ge 3\end{cases}$$

we ought to have

$$H_n(X) = \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z} & n=0,1,2 \\ 0 & n\ge 3\end{cases}$$

Comment: To be clear, this $U$ and $V$ are not the same as the $U$ and $V$ that the question proposes using.  (Well, $U$ is essentially the same, but $V$ is not--OP's $V$ extends to contain the whole inner loop of the croissant.)

Comment: @EricWofsey Mm, I see. The $V$ given by the OP is essentially $X$ with a closed disk cut out — is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, that's right.  $U$ is $X$ with the special point removed, and $V$ is $X$ with a non-special point removed.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks for the comment. I’ve edited my answer to better address the OP’s question.

Comment: @SantanaAfton 
To what space is homotopically equivalent $U\cap V$ according to the new choice of open? To two points?

Comment: @EricWofsey To what space is homotopically equivalent $U\cap V$ according to the new choice of open? To two points?

Comment: @user424241 What is the intersection of two overlapping open cylinders? Here $U\cap V$ is the disjoint union of two such intersections.

Answer (score 1):

Regard $X$ instead as  $S^2 \coprod I/(0,0,\pm 1) \sim (\pm 1)$, where $I=[-1,1]$. This is $S^2$ with a line segment joining the north and south pole. Up to homotopy equivalence, this is your space. Using your neighborhoods, you will find that $U \cap V \cong S^1\times I \coprod I$ (of course up to homotopy we can push down to get $S^1 \coprod pt$. Then by Mayer Vietors and the LES of reduced homology, we get

$$0 \to \tilde{H}_2(X) \to \tilde{H}_1(U\cap V ) \to 0 \to \tilde{H}_1(X) \to \tilde{H}_0(U \cap V) \to 0$$

From this, you will deduce that $H_2(X)=\mathbb Z$ and $H_1(X)=\mathbb Z$ and zero everywhere  else.

Actually if you stop and ponder what $X$ is, you might notice that $I$ might be outside of the sphere, and you can in fact contract the endpoints of $I$ to a point, and note that $X=S^2 \vee S^1$ up to homotopy equivalence.

---

If you are insistent on not changing the problem at all, then you can prove that $U \cap V$ is still $(S^1 \times I) \coprod pt$ set theoretically, where $pt=\{(0,0,1),(0,0,-1)\}$ Since $pt \in U,V$ and the rest is the usual intersection.