# Homological groups of the $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ and quotient out the circle $S^1 \times \lbrace x \rbrace$ for some point $x \in S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

**Homological groups of the $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ and quotient out the circle $S^1 \times \lbrace x \rbrace$ for some point $x \in S^1$**

I am trying to calculate the homology groups of this space, but first, I would like to know what this space looks like, that is, what topological space it looks like and what the difference if we made the quotient not for $S^1 \times \lbrace x \rbrace$  but for $ \lbrace x \rbrace\times S^1$ , thank you.

Comment: Obviously it doesn't make a difference whether you quotient out $S^1\times\{x\}$ or $\{x\}\times S^1$ since swapping the coordinates is a homeomorphism $T^2\to T^2$.

Comment: @EricWofsey 
In other words, this space is homotopically equivalent to the sphere where the north pole and the south pole are identified?, which is homotopically equivalent to $S^2\vee S^1$?

Comment: @Nash That is correct.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3299221/274352) is related, though it realizes your space in a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Presumably you're quotienting out the co-ordinate circles here (that is, the ones which go "horizontally" and "vertically" around the torus.

I should point out that what I'm about to say is all going to be rather imprecise, but since you're asking about what stuff "looks like" I think that's okay.

If you quotient out the "horizontal" circle, you get a $T^2$ without the hole in the middle - you've closed up that hole because you've identified the $S^1$ which went around it to a point.

If you quotient out the "vertical" $S^1$, you get something which still looks like $T^2$, but is a sort of stretched out cresent moon. That is, if you imagine a cresent moon and then you take the two tips and stretch them around to join them together. You have this hole in the middle as you started with the $T^2$, but now you've taken a circle which sits around the outsi-... **Ugh**. I realise now this takes an effort to explain in words. Here's a picture of this second quotient:

[image: Torus quotient]

I can't find a good picture of the first one online, but that's easier to visualise anyway.

The homologies of these two spaces are of course the same because they're homeomorphic - but this is not obvious when you have pictures of these spaces in your head! Thanks, Algebraic Topology :)

Comment: so what would the space $T^2 = S^1 \times S^1$ and quotient out two different circles $S^1 \times \lbrace x \rbrace$ and $S^1 \times \lbrace y \rbrace$ be like?

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand this question. Is this not exactly answered in my answer above?