# Calculating homology groups for disconnected spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm working on this question about calculating homology using Mayer-Vietoris sequence: [homology groups of the quotient of $\mathbb{S}^2$ obtained by identifying north and south poles to a point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3299221/homology-groups-of-the-quotient-of-mathbbs2-obtained-by-identifying-north).

Using the leading answer's sets for $U$ and $V$, I get that $U \cap V \simeq S^1 \sqcup S^1 $ which leads me to this question:

TL;DR **How can I calculate the homology of a disconnected space?**

Comment: The homology of a disconnected space is just the direct sum of homologies, you can prove this from the definitions

Answer (score 3):

I will discuss singular homology. Similar arguments work in other homology theories, they just have different definitions for their chain complexes.

Let $X = X_1 \sqcup X_2$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are open non-empty subsets of $X$. Since each simplex $\Delta^k$ is connected, a continuous function $f\colon\Delta^k \to X$ either has its image entirely in $X_1$ or $X_2$. Moreover if $im(f)\subset X_i$ then each face of $f$ is contained in $X_i$ as well. It follows that

$$ C_\bullet(X) \cong C_\bullet(X_1) \oplus C_\bullet(X_2) $$

as chain complexes, in particular the boundary operator $\partial$ on $C_\bullet(X)$ is the direct sum $\partial_1\oplus \partial_2$ of the boundary operators for $X_1$ and $X_2$. As a consequence you get

$$H_k(X) \cong H_k(X_1) \oplus H_k(X_2) $$

for all $k$.